# Save checkbox button state using userdefaults in swift

Tags: ios, swift, checkbox, uibutton, nsuserdefaults

view controller had two check boxes buttons 
1.chekcIn
2.checkOut

am saving the checkIN [ checkbox button] status in user defaults, working fine but when am using that userdefaults key in Nextviewcontroller its always showing true and not running into false block 
this is the code

inHomeview controller

```
@IBAction func CheckInButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {


        for senderdata in checkINOUT {
            senderdata.setImage( UIImage(named:"uncheck1"), for: .normal)
            print("uncheck is called")

        }


        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"check1"), for: .normal)
         prefs.set(true, forKey: "check")
    prefs.synchronize()

    }
```

nextviewcontroller

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
{        

 let prefs:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
  if  prefs.bool(forKey: "check") ==true
        {
        print("select")

        } else {

            print("unselect")
        }

 }
```

check box select its execute main block if unselect execute else block

how to over come this problem where I did mistake

Answer (score 1):

You´re not setting your `userDefault` value to `false`. You´re only setting it to true, that´s why it´s always `true`. And btw no need to use `synchronize()` Change your code to the following instead:

HomeViewController:

```
@IBAction func CheckInButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    for senderdata in checkINOUT {
        senderdata.setImage( UIImage(named:"uncheck1"), for: .normal)
        print("uncheck is called")
    }
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"check1"), for: .normal)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "check")
}
```

NextViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()       

    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "check") {
        print("select")
    } else {
        print("unselect") {
    }
}
```

**So do check where you want to set your `check` value to `false` and use it.**

**Update:**
Just do this check:

```
if UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "check") {
    // Show data
} else {
    // segue to another viewController
}
```

Comment: if check is false then I can call other view controller. if check is true  I have to show the data on in same view controller

Answer (score 0):

When you set "check" value as true once, it will always true, until you set "check" value to false.
I think you should add some code to set "check" to false, when user not select the checkbox.